# Remove duplicate column indexes from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a solution to removing duplicate column indexes in my dataframe- what I need to do is to add the values in the duplicate columns row by row and then keep only 1 of these columns with the summed value

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0,0,0,1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1]]), columns=[1,1,2,2,2,3,3], index=[1,2,3])

   1  1  2  2  2  3  3
1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

should become

```
   1  2  3
1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  1
```

Comment: you have duplicated column names in your df?

Comment: Yes- I needed to create dummy variables for categorical columns- turns out across columns there were same categories too- hence the complication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the missing data, an ugly attempt to your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0,0,0,1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0,0], 
                            [0,0,0,0,0,0,1]]))
df.columns = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
df1 = df.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).sum()
df1.index = range(1,4)
df1
```

outputs the desired dataframe you posted. The following `df1.index = range(1,4)` is just to re-index the rows because they start with `1` in your  example.

Answer (score 2):

Simply group by columns:

```
df.groupby(df.columns, 1).sum()

   1  2  3
1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  1
```

Or as pointed out by @user2285236

```
df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()
```

Comment: Or `df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()`

Comment: Nice! very concise.

Answer (score 2):

you do not need `groupby` here

```
df.sum(level=0,axis=1)
Out[358]: 
   1  2  3
1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Comment: also need to sum up the values in duplicate columns

Comment: Ah! Then my answer won’t do! ;) as I thought he wanted to remove duplicates and keep only the last occurrence